# BIOS firmware password and security feature differences

Tags: bios, passwords, firmware

I am looking for an explanation and perhaps some references on the different types of BIOS security password features.

**Example BIOS Setting Options**

> - BIOS Password
> - BIOS Administrator Password
> - BIOS Startup Password
> - BIOS Supervisor Password

Comment: Anyone, I think that any single machine cannot have all those passwords at the same time. I just wanna know the differences between those bios passwords to be able to work property with them in any machine (PC or Laptop) that I gonna work with.

Comment: PIMP_jUICE_IT I am not trying to troubleshoot any specific machine, so I cannot say any specific make or model. I just wanna a clarification about those term definitions. Probably the definition of those terms depends of the manufacturer and how he called the different bios passwords as you explained in the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really comes down to the [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) firmware version of each particular device (or the make and model of the "machine") and what the ***vendor*** which wrote it to support, classifies these security features as, and so on.

1. According to [Enable BIOS Passwords for Extra
   Security](http://www.pcworld.com/article/158292/Enable_BIOS_Passwords_for_Extra_Security.html)
   the options on a common ***PhoenixBIOS*** system could be:

   - > <sub>**Supervisor Password:** Enable and change this password to prevent someone from changing these BIOS settings in the future. For example,
     >   if you don't want someone booting from a CD or external drive on one
     >   of your work systems, first disable those options in the Boot menu,
     >   and then enable the password here. If troubleshooting in the future,
     >   you can restore those boot options after entering the BIOS password.</sub>
     >
     > <sub>**User Password:** Add an extra password prompt before getting to the Windows login screen. This provides a small, extra security step
     >   against unauthorized access. First set the user password, then enable
     >   it on boot.</sub>
     >
     > <sub>**HDD Password:** For the best disk protection short of encrypting your drive, enable the hard disk password. If this option is supported
     >   on your system, the password settings are stored on the disk itself,
     >   preventing access even if installed in another PC. A data-recovery
     >   service could likely still access your files since they're
     >   unencrypted. So remember that it's still possible—although quite
     >   difficult—for someone else to access the data.</sub>
     >
     > <sub><sub>[source](http://www.pcworld.com/article/158292/Enable_BIOS_Passwords_for_Extra_Security.html)</sub></sub>

---

2. According to [How many different types of passwords do you know on a PC?](http://www.windowspasswordsrecovery.com/different-types-of-computer-password.htm) referencing mainly ***ThinkPad*** make and model hardware these could be classified as such:

   - > <sub>**Power-on password**</sub>
     >
     > <sub>Power-on PasswordA Power-on password protects the system from being
     >   powered on by an unauthorized person. The following is the icon that
     >   comes up in the upper left corner if a Power-on password is set:</sub>
     >
     > <sub>*Normal operation*</sub>
     >
     > <sub>When the Power-on password has been set, a prompt will appear during
     >   the system start up, and the Power-on password must be entered before
     >   an operating system can be booted.</sub>
     >
     > <sub>**Hard drive password**</sub>
     >
     > <sub>Hard drive passwordThere are two Hard drive passwords: a user Hard
     >   drive password for the user and a master Hard drive password for the
     >   system administrator. The administrator can use the master password to
     >   get access to the hard drive even if a user has changed the user Hard
     >   drive password. The following is the icon that comes up in the upper
     >   left corner if a Hard disk password is set:</sub>
     >
     > <sub>*Normal operation*</sub>
     >
     > <sub>There are two modes for the Hard drive password: user only and
     >   master + user. The master + user mode requires two Hard drive passwords; the 
     >   system administrator enters both in the same operation and provides
     >   the user Hard drive password to the system user. If either master +
     >   user or user only are set, a the password prompt will appear during
     >   the boot process either the master or the user Hard drive password
     >   will need to be entered before the operating system can be
     >   booted.</sub>
     >
     > <sub>**Supervisor password (BIOS password)**</sub>
     >
     > <sub>Supervisor BIOS passwordA Supervisor password protects the system
     >   information stored in the BIOS. The user must enter the Supervisor
     >   password in order to get access to the ThinkPad BIOS Setup Utility in
     >   order to change the system configuration. If the Supervisor password
     >   is forgotten there is no way to reset it to enter the BIOS
     >   configuration. Setting a Supervisor password automatically sets the
     >   master Hard drive password. The following is the icon that comes up in
     >   the upper left corner if a Supervisor password is set:</sub>
     >
     > <sub>*Normal operation*</sub>
     >
     > <sub>When the Supervisor password is set, then a prompt will appear when
     >   entering the ThinkPad BIOS setup utility and the Supervisor password
     >   will need to be entered before access will be granted to view or
     >   change settings.</sub>
     >
     > <sub>**Note:** Setting the Supervisor password does not prevent access to the operating system. If the user Hard drive password and Power-on
     >   password are not set, then setting a Supervisor password will not
     >   cause the password prompt to appear when the operating system is
     >   booted.</sub>
     >
     > <sub><sub>[source](http://www.windowspasswordsrecovery.com/different-types-of-computer-password.htm)</sub></sub>